# Syntax error when running RVM function

Tags: ruby, installation, rvm

First of all, I'm running bash 3.2.48 on mac osx 10.7.1 with xCode 4 installed.

I've downloaded RVM like specified in the official documentation but when I do

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

I get an error

```
-bash: /Users/kevin/.rvm/scripts/rvm: line 28: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
-bash: /Users/kevin/.rvm/scripts/rvm: line 28: `  done'
```

I've searched either on Google, the rvm github issue tracker and stackoverflow but I didn't get any info on similar issue or anything that helped me find a solution.

Nobody seems to have trouble like this installing RVM 1.8.3 so I guess something is going wrong when I install on my mac.

Here's the corresponding part of the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# rvm : Ruby enVironment Manager
# https://rvm.beginrescueend.com
# https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm

# Is RVM loaded as a shell function already?

export HOME="${HOME%%+(\/)}" # Remove trailing slashes if they exist on HOME

if (( ${rvm_ignore_rvmrc:=0} == 0 ))
then
  for rvmrc in /etc/rvmrc "$HOME/.rvmrc"
  do
    if [[ -f "$rvmrc" ]]
    then
      if \grep '^\s*rvm .*$' "$rvmrc" >/dev/null 2>&1
      then
        printf "\nError:
        $rvmrc is for rvm settings only.
        rvm CLI may NOT be called from within $rvmrc.
        Skipping the loading of $rvmrc"
        return 1
      else
        source "$rvmrc"
      fi
    fi
  done
fi
```

The error triggers on `done` just before the last `if`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** I found the problem, I mispelled an alias as `fi`. I just renamed it and it worked.

Thank you for your help. Sorry for this useless question.

Comment: Maybe if you posted the script that contains the error someone could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're not supposed to type that but rather add it to your ~/.bash_profile at least that's how I did it on linux before, could you point where are you reading the steps for installation from?

Comment: I added it to my profile already but it didn't work. The difference is that if I do it manually it only load rvm for the current session only.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, thats not for running at the commandline, that goes in your .bash_profile or .bashrc (with a corresponding

if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
  source $HOME/.bashrc
 fi

in your .bash_profile)

Comment: I too use OS X Lion, having migrated from Snow Leopard. Then again, I also have Debian, Ubuntu, CentOS, OpenSUSE, and FreeBSD here as well.

Comment: OK, but like I said it is in my .bash_profile at the bottom and I already source the .bashrc (before loading rvm) that itself source my aliases. When I open a new shell session it shows exactly the same error.

Comment: try changing it to

`for rvmrc in {/etc/rvmrc,$HOME/.rvmrc}`

Comment: OK, if your bash side is giving you problems but not the zsh it means your bash side is polluted somehow. 

`sudo rm -rf /etc/rvmrc /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh /usr/local/rvm /usr/local/bin/rvm $HOME/.rvm $HOME/.rvmrc`

Don't su to root and do this, exactly as I showed you do. use sudo. Then make sure you comment out the RVM load line in your .bash_profile and/or .bashrc. Then log your user out *completely*. Now, try your installation again.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work either, I've done exactly want you wrote though. I still get the same syntax error when I open the terminal. I wonder if it could not be because of an error in my .bash files just before the line that loads rvm. Will check it.

Answer (score 0):

So I decided to switch to zsh for a few reasons and it worked without doing anything but putting the line into the zshrc. But I will try to find the problem anyway.